# How to perform a click on alertDialog PositiveButton programatically?

Tags: android, runtime, android-alertdialog

I have this code in which I want to programmatically click the positive Button of an AlertDialog that was shown before the current AlertDialog.

Down below is the code:

```
          ad.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                int[] serial=new int[10];
                int length = 0;
                int itemNotFound = 0;
                String firstItem=null;
                float firstPrate=0;
                float firstQuant=0;
                boolean status=true;
                for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                serial[i]=rowValidator(i);
                if(serial[i]==0)
                    length=i;
                }


                for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
                    if(serial[i]==3)
                        itemNotFound++;
                }

                if(itemNotFound>0){

                    for(int i=0;i<length;i++){

                        if(serial[i]==3){
                            firstItem=items[i].getText().toString();
                            firstPrate=rate[i];
                            firstQuant=quant[i];
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    AlertDialog d=new AlertDialog.Builder(PurchaseVoucher.this).create();
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)PurchaseVoucher.this.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
                    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog, null);
                    d.setView(view);
                    d.setTitle("Add item(s) to inventory");
                    TextView tv=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.alertDialogID);
                    CheckBox cb=(CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                    cb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    tv.setText("Do you want to add "+firstItem+" to your inventory?");
                    if((itemNotFound-1)>0){
                        cb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        cb.setText("Do this for the next "+(itemNotFound-1)+" conflict(s)");
                    }
                    d.show();

                    if(!cb.isChecked()){

                        PurchaseVoucher.this.dbControl.addOrUpdateStock(firstItem, firstPrate, 0, firstQuant);


                    }
```

i want to initiate the click if(!cb.isChecked)
Unfortunatly I can set button clicks for an independent button but how will i do this?? I want AlertDialog ad's positiveButton to be clicked so a new alertDialog d is shown.

Comment: use `button.performClick()` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick()

Comment: this method works on independent buttons. In this case I am confused, what should be before '.performClick()'

Comment: Got it, use Button n=AlertDialog.getButton() method to get the button object.
Then use n.performClick()

Answer (score 4):

Use this method to click programatically

```
ad.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).performClick();
```